# refactor lambda to be called by another class: while keeping caller's code to be still short

Tags: c++11, lambda

How to professionally refactor lambda function to be called by another class WHILE make caller's code still short?

My attempt shows that for changing a lambda function to a normal function, I have to capture variables manually, thus the new normal function requires more parameters (to compensate automatic capture ability).

As a result, the new function is more tedious to use, and can cause more bug.

### Example

Here is my original code, using lambda.

```
void Turret::registerFullversion(int gameObjectId, PhysicObject* phyO){//utility
    //.... something a bit complex .......
}
void Turret::createTurret(int typeOfTurret){
    int gameObjectId=createNewGameObjectId();
    auto registerEasy=[&]( PhysicObject* phyO){
        //^ served as a short hand version of "registerFullversion"
        //  1 parameter is more comfortable than 2
        registerFullversion(gameObjectId,phyO);
    }
    switch(typeOfTurret){
        case 1:{ //this part will be moved into another class (###)
            PhysicObject* phy=PhysicSystem::createNewPhysicObject();
            registerEasy( phy);
            //^ equivalent to "registerFullversion(gameObjectId,phy)"
            //  but it is very concise (1 parameter), nice!
        };break;
        //..... a lot of case ....
    }
    //... do something about "gameObjectId"
}
```

I want to move a part of function (###) from `Turret` into another class (`TurretLaser`).

It works, but the result is that caller have to capture `gameObjectId` and pass it manually :-

```
void Turret::createTurret(int typeOfTurret){
    int gameObjectId=createNewGameObjectId();
    switch(typeOfTurret){
        case 1:{ //this part have to be move into another class
            TurretLaser::createTurret(gameObjectId)
        };break;
        //..... a lot of case ....
    }
}
void TurretLaser::createTurret(int gameObjectId){ //(###)
    PhysicObject* phy=PhysicSystem::createNewPhysicObject();
    Turret:registerFullversion(gameObjectId,phy);
    //^ it is not as short as before  (now = 2 parameters)
}
```

### **Note**

- In real case, all above functions are non-static function, and all functions are far more complex.
- Performance is the first priority.  Thus, `std::bind` and `std::function` are not allowed.
- This question asks about how to omit the captured parameters rather than "Please fix my code", so a valid solution can also just provide a new example with its own fix instead of showing modification of my code.

### My attempt

I will manually capture the related data (`gameObjectId`) and cache it (using a new variable `CACHE_gameObjectId`):-

```
void Turret::registerEasy(PhysicObject* physicO){
    registerFullversion(CACHE_gameObjectId,physicO);
    //int "CACHE_gameObjectId" is a new field of "Turret"
};
void Turret::createTurret(int typeOfTurret){
    int gameObjectId=createNewGameObjectId();
    Turret::CACHE_gameObjectId=gameObjectId;
    switch(typeOfTurret){
        case 1:{ //this part have to be move into another class
            TurretLaser::createTurret(gameObjectId)
        };break;
        //..... a lot of case ....
    }
}
void TurretLaser::createTurret(int gameObjectId){ //(###)
    PhysicObject* phy=PhysicSystem::createNewPhysicObject();
    Turret:registerEasy(phy);
    //^ short as before, nice
}
```

**Disadvantage of my solution:** dirty, look dangerous (not so automatic, thus can cause more bug) , seem to be less thread-safe (?)

Comment: I'm not going to vote but it's not clear at all what you want to achieve, but this could be me not getting it. If a function needs 2 arguments, I would just call it with 2 args, that's the most understandable way? Why a lambda at all?

Comment: It is easier to call it with 1 argument. ........ Here is the flow of standard calling :  1. `Turret::createTurret`  -> 2. `TurretLaser::createTurret` -> 3. `Turret:registerFullversion`  . ...... The value of parameter `gameObjectId` is known since 1.  ........ So, in the last calling, I wish I can omit `gameObjectId` (i.e. call `Turret::registerEasy` instead of `Turret:registerFullversion`).

Comment: IMHO passing around a single `int` value is better than designing a whole mess of code just to avoid this. Copying an `int` is a cheap operation, and you're going to do it anyway to capture it into your lambda.

Comment: Well, this is where we seem to disagree: I would (strongly) prefer to pass one more argument (even if there are many calls), than using a lambda, which's only purpose seems to be to capture the second argument.

Comment: @Chnossos  Thank for valuable feedback.  I just think that there is some "a whole mess of code" that is still easy enough to try. (C++ is new for me.)

Comment: @alain  Thank for understanding.  Your opinion somehow enlightens me  ... I just still hope that some trick (RAII?) that can solve it elegantly.

Comment: Is your `gameObjectId` used after the switch ? If no, why not call `createNewGameObjectId()` directly inside the desired (member) function ?

Comment: @Chnossos It is used.  Sorry for being unclear, I will edit the question.  Thank.